# DataGridView::CellBeginEdit event not firing

Tags: c#, datagridview

Using C# .NET 4.7.2 in Visual Studio 2019. Simple WinForms application with a DataGridView. After reading some data from a database, the data displays fine in the DataGridView.

After hooking up the `CellBeginEdit` event, the event handler is never fired. Tried a few other events, such as `CellContentClick`, `CellEnter`, `CellClick`, and all these events fire as normal.

I then added a second DataGridView control to the form, and displayed the data in this second grid. The `CellBeginEdit` event works as expected in the 2nd grid.

After reviewing settings for the original and new DataGridView controls in the `Designer.cs` file, nothing obvious explains the different behaviour.

What prevents `CellBeginEdit` from firing on a grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, this is embarrassing. Turns out the `ReadOnly` property was set on the original DataGridView. I don't remember changing this property, but had changed `MultiSelect` which is just above `ReadOnly` in the Designer...possibly accidentally changed the setting at that time.

Will leave this here in case somebody else finds this useful.